Microsoft365R Package 404 on list_sharepoint_sites()
When i try execute the below i get a 404 error. But i can used get_sharepoint_site("my site") to work fine. Any ideas? Am i using it wrong?
Microsoft365R::list_sharepoint_sites(auth_type="device_code")
    Creating Microsoft Graph login for default tenant
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code <code> to authenticate. 
Waiting for device code in browser...
Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort
Authentication complete.
Error in process_response(res, match.arg(http_status_handler), simplify) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404). Failed to complete operation. Message:
Requested site could not be found.

